# exporting data from Kendo-UI grid

Tags: kendo-grid

The KendoUI grid code in my application is declarative-style, like this:

```
<kendo-grid id="myGrid" options="mainGridOptions">
    <kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
            <button kendoGridExcelCommand>Export to Excel</button>
         <kendo-grid-excel fileName="GridData.xlsx">
           </kendo-grid-excel>
    </kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <div k-detail-template>
        <kendo-tabstrip> Some DIVs and fields here </kendo-tabstrip>
    </div>
   <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx"></kendo-grid-excel>
</kendo-grid>
```

The data source to this grid is attached on run-time. I am trying to make the ***Export to Excel*** button workable but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumble upon this question in future, here is the solution. If a template is used, then the button that will export the Grid to Excel has to programmatically call the saveAsExcel method. Because I was using a template, I added a button and wrote its onclick event like this:

```
<button id='exportEx' onclick='$("#myGrid").data("kendo-grid").saveAsExcel();'>Export to Excel</button>
```